# Two item category coupon code with fixed amount for whole cart

Tags: category, magento-1, cart, coupon-codes, magento1.9.2.4

Magento version, 1.9.2.4

How do I generate a coupon where a person puts in there cart one item each from two different categories and then gets a fixed discount off the whole cart.

But, if only one item is in the cart from one category, then it won't allow the coupon to be validated?

For example, customer orders one vacuum (from category 4) and one bag (from category 5), then they get a fixed off amount.  But if they only order the vacuum the coupon is invalidated.

I ask because if I just say

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
Category  is  4, 5

It will work if only 4 is in the cart and 5 is missing.  There has got to be a step that I am missing.

ANy help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER:

In conditions:

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true:

Category  is  4

If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true:

Category  is  5

---

In actions:

If ANY  of these conditions are TRUE :

Category  **is one of**  4
Category  **is one of**  5